# Formula to get number of expected successes over n number of trials given a probability

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

I was just wondering if a formula existed that gave a number of expected successes over a number of trials.

For example:

If there is a 1 in 50,000 chance of something happening, and you run 1 million trials, how often would you expect a 'success' to happen! I looked online but wasn't able to find this and I don't really have a background in mathematics, I was just interested in knowing if a formula for this existed is all.

Comment: If you run $N$ trials, each with probability of success $p$ the expected number of success is $Np$.

Answer (score 1):

If the probability $p$ of a success does not change between independent trials, then the number of 'successes' are given by a binomial distribution; that is, the probability of getting $k$ successes in $n$ trials is:

$$
P(k \text{ success in } n \text{ trials}) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.
$$

where

$$
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.
$$

In your case, you would use $p = 1/50000$ and $n = 1000000$.

The expected number of successes is $pn$, so using your numbers, we would expect $1/50000 \cdot 1000000 = 20$ successes.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Comment: Need that the trials are independent too.